# Parse JSON with Gson

Tags: java, parsing, gson

How can I parse the JSON below with Gson?

Now I use:

```
private AttachChildDataModel parseSuccess(String content){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(content, AttachChildDataModel.class);
}
```

Where `AttachChildDataModel` has these member variables:

```
private Integer adultId;
private Integer childId;
private PlatformEnum platform;
private String regId;
private Date loginDate;
private Date logoutDate;
private ClientApp clientApp;
```

The Json string I'm trying to parse is:

```
{"log":  
  {
    "childId":2,
    "adultId":1,
    "logoutDate":null,
    "platform":"IPHONE",
    "regId":null,
    "loginDate":1325419200000,
    "clientApp":"CHILD_APP"
  }
}
```

When I put the object into the Spring ModelView, I add it under name `log`. The problematic thing is when I try to parse it with Gson. Right now, I manually remove the "log" prefix and the "}" postfix with `String#substring`, but I think there's a better solution.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, just create a "foo" class like this:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q15614008;

public class Foo {

   public AttachChildDataModel log;

}
```

and use it as base class for parsing in Gson:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q15614008;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class Q15614008 {

  public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String testString = "{\"log\": "
        + "  {"
        + "\"childId\":2," + "\"adultId\":1,"
        + "\"logoutDate\":null,"
        + "\"platform\":\"IPHONE\","
        + "\"regId\":null,"
        + "\"loginDate\":1325419200000,"
        + "\"clientApp\":\"CHILD_APP\"}"
        + "}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Foo foo = gson.fromJson(
        testString, Foo.class);
    System.out.println("Result: " + foo.log.toString());
  }

}
```

Then use only the `log` member variable of the `Foo` class.